# VB.NET - QueueUserWorkItem Completion

Tags: vb.net

I have an Array `sources()` containing a few Web Page links, They go through the `GrabProxies()` function.

```
For Each source In sources
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf GrabProxies), source)
Next
```

I use a simple Variable Incrementing method to check if all sources are finished or not. The issue is that it isn't efficient, Half of the time it doesn't detect it (Probably because two threads finish at the exact same time or something?)

```
Dim Sources_CountTemp As Integer
Private Function GrabProxies(source As String)
(...)
If Sources_CountTemp = sources.Count Then

    console.writeline("Finished!")

End If
```

Either way, It's not an efficient way to get this to work. How can I manage to get it signal and complete a small amount of code when its finished?

EDIT: The variable method is really un-efficient I ran 8 runs of it of a Long Function (20-30 seconds before it finishes) and only 4/8 times it actually worked. (Using 15 threads)

EDIT 2: Seems to work more of the time once I used a `New Random()` on the Source Array. So that means seems like when Time Out issues etc happen it makes it not work as much.

Is there a way to maybe check if any ThreadPool threads are running? And if 0 is running then do an action? Just guessing here. If you have any idea on how I should do this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Honestly no idea why this works as realistically it shouldnt make a difference but I tested 10 times and all 10 times it worked!

Replace
`Sources_CountTemp += 1` (Or whatever kind of Incrementation Method you use) with:

`Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() Sources_CountTemp += 1))`

Comment: You have a race condition - so pushing the increment to the UI eliminates the race.